# How to find users versions of Android in Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console

I would like to see which versions of Android OS (API) our users using our app have?
At least in proportion to the percentage.
There was a major update in Google Play Console (2020), and I can't find it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to Statistics
2. Click the dropdown and select Users > Active Users > All users
3. Bellow that select: View by Android Version

Now you can see how much users are using each Android Version

Answer (score 3):

And here is also an answer for those who are blind as me :D.
[image]